# How to pass parameters to Primefaces LazyDataModel load function

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading, jsf-2.2

I have a implemented a lazy loading Datatable with primefaces that implements

```
load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)
```

Now I need to pass parameters from my page to this method (i.e., I have a filter section in my page, the filters are not part of the table, and are independent objects!). My parameters are stored in the page's managed bean.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the parameter(s) a property of the bean, and pass them directly to the service that fetches the data from the db (in this example the service is the EJB `MyObjFacade myObjFacade`):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    @EJB
    private MyObjFacade myObjFacade;
    private LazyDataModel<MyObjType> model;        // getter
    private MyParameter myParameter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new LazyDataModel<MyObjType> () {

            @Override
            public List<MyObjType> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
                model.setRowCount(myObjFacade.count(filters, myParameter));
                return myObjFacade.getResultList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters, myParameter);
            }
        };
        model.setRowCount(myObjFacade.count(new HashMap<String, String> ()));
    }
}
```

You simply have to provide the service implementing `count` and `getResultList` methods.

Comment: Can't I use two diferente classes? As specified here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml.

Comment: In theory you should be able to use different classes, although it will be more difficult to handle some things: for the data source injection, the model should be either an EJB or a view scoped bean. Try it, and if necessary post the code in a new question.

Comment: This works (I kind of do it the same). You can even make this into a sort of baseclass and very easily add basic things like 'multi-tenancy' and more

Answer (score -1):

After many hours searching I finally did it. I leave here my solution for further reference.

```
//Managed Bean - View
public class DummyLazySearchPageBean {

    private LazyDataModel<DummyObject> results;
    private String searchFilter;//to simulate search filter
    private DummyBusinessClass dummyBusinessClass;

    public DummyLazySearchPageBean() {
        results = new SearchsLazyLoader();
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private final class SearchsLazyLoader extends LazyDataModel<DummyObject> {
        @Override  
        public List<DummyObject> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
//Simulate BD model         
List<DummyObject> data = new ArrayList<DummyObject>();
            dummyBusinessClass = new DummyBusinessClass();

            data = dummyBusinessClass.search(searchFilter, 5000);

            //rowCount
            this.setRowCount(data.size());

              //paginate
              if(data.size() > pageSize) {
                  try {
                      return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
                  }
                  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                      return data.subList(first, first + (data.size() % pageSize));
                  }
              }
              else {
                  return data;
              }
        }
    }

    public final void search(){
        results = new SearchsLazyLoader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing some explanation (might work, but does not look that different than the original answer)

Answer (score -1):

Just Create Constructor of SearchsLazyLoader with parameter input.
This is sample of my code:

```
package com.mandiri.askes.model.lazy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

import com.mandiri.askes.model.Participant;
import com.mandiri.askes.utils.CallAble;
import com.mandiri.askes.utils.HibernateUtil;

public class LazyPesertaDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Participant> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String keyword;

    public LazyPesertaDataModel(String keyword) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(keyword)) {
            this.keyword = keyword;
        }else{
            this.keyword = "";
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Collect Peserta Badan Usaha as Data Model Primefaces
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public List<Participant> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
            SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

        List<Participant> listPesertaBpjs = new ArrayList<Participant>();

        listPesertaBpjs = getLazyDataPeserta(first, pageSize, sortField);

        this.setRowCount(countAllRecord());

        return listPesertaBpjs;
    }

    /**
     * Get Peserta Data using hibernate pagination <b>(Lazy Loading)</b> Technique.
     * 
     * @author Dibrut
     * @param firstRecord
     * @param maxResult
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Participant> getLazyDataPeserta(final int firstRecord, final int maxResult, final String sortField) {
        return HibernateUtil.doInTransaction(new CallAble<List<Participant>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Participant> call(Session session) throws Exception {

                List<Participant> pesertaList = new ArrayList<Participant>();
                String hql = "FROM com.dibrut.learn.model.Participant P"
                        + " WHERE P.name LIKE :keyword";

                Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(firstRecord).
                        setMaxResults(maxResult).setString("keyword", "%"+keyword+"%");

                pesertaList = query.list();
                return pesertaList;
            }
        });     
    }

    /**
     * Count total participant
     * @return
     * @author Dibrut
     */
    public int countAllRecord(){
        return HibernateUtil.doInTransaction(new CallAble<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer call(Session session) throws Exception {             
                String hql = "FROM com.dibrut.learn.model.Participant P"
                        + " WHERE P.name LIKE :keyword";

                Long totalPesertaBu = (Long) session.createQuery(hql).                      
                        setString("keyword", "%"+ keyword+"%").
                        uniqueResult(); 

                return totalPesertaBu.intValue();
            }
        });     
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

}
```

if you want to search the data, just call the constructor with parameter of your managedBean property. for example you have searchParticipant method in your ManagedBean:

```
public void searchParticipant() {
    this.participantLazyModel = new LazyPesertaDataModel(this.keyword);     
}
```

where the keyword is value of inputText from your page.

Comment: Works but the other answer is more in line with what I do, looks 'simpler'